# ¿como agregar un nuevo campo a todos los registros encontrados mediante una consulta sql con eloquent?- laravel8

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

tengo una tabla products, y obtengo los productos almacenados con la siguiente consulta: `Products::where('all_supply','<','min-supply')->get();`
ahora, lo que busco es agregarle un nuevo campo a todos estos registros llamado **type** con value "fecha" me refiero a agregarlo a la consulta ya creada y no agregarlo a la base de datos.

Con la consulta que hago me trae estos registros como ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a la hora de agregar al campo type quede de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De que manera puedo agregar ese nuevo campo a los registros que ya traje con la consulta?

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar un raw select? `...->addSelect(DB::raw("'type' as someValue"));`

Comment: porque no sabia que existia ese metodo jaja, no encontré documentación en español de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como se haría en una consulta directa de SQL.

```
SELECT *, 'type' as fecha FROM ...
```

Puedes replicarlo utilizando distintos métodos query builder que laravel ofrece, uno de ellos es `addSelect()`.

```
Products::where('all_supply','<','min-supply')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw("'type' as someValue"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: gracias :), funciona.